# How do I specify the format for url_for in a nested route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following link_to statement:

```
  <%= link_to image_tag("icons/document_24.png"),
              [program_code.program, program_code],
              :class      => :no_hover,
              :alt        => "Print Tracking Code",
              :title      => "Print Tracking Code",
              :target     => :new
  %>
```

will generate a url like `/programs/1/program_codes/1`

If I want the url to be `/programs/1/program_codes/1.svg`, how do I specify the format in the array that is being passed to `url_for`?  I've searched the Rails API documentation and looked at several examples but have been unable to find anything like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your looking for the **:format** option. It will append the file extension to the link e.g. '.svg'

Make sure you put the :format option in the path building hash of the link_to method.

```
<%= link_to 'somewhere', {somewhere_to_path(@var), :format => "svg"},:title => "Print Tracking Code", :target => "_blank" %>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I got that from the docs, but if you look at my example, there is an array passed to url_for (due to nested resources), which is what is hanging me up.  I've tried, passing :format => "svg" and :format => :svg within the array and outside it and it doesn't seem to work either way. Very confusing.

Comment: Is there a reason your not using a named route? then you could have somthing like {program_code_path(program_code.program, program_code), :format => "svg"}

Comment: I'll have to try that.  This code was written by a pro Ruby firm, so not sure why named routes were not used--most of the code they wrote is pristine otherwise, so I assumed there must be a reason they did it this way that I just didn't understand yet.

Comment: one reason would be if you had a polymorphic association. For instance, if you had ... say ... ManagedServer and UnmanagedServer which had different attributes. But they both had "alerts". you might want something like url_for([@server, :alerts, {format: :xml}]) ( or whatever, I haven't figured it out yet.)

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with a specific class and can use a named route, that is the most efficient option. But if you're dealing with nested resources and the parent resource isn't fixed (for instance, in a polymorphic association), AND you want to specify a format, url_for doesn't meet your needs.

Fortunately you can use `polymorphic_url`.

For instance, if `server` could be an instance of ManagedServer or UnmanagedServer, and both can have alerts, you can do this:

```
polymorphic_url([server, :alerts], :format => :xml)
```

and that will give you

```
/managed_server/123/alerts.xml
/unmanaged_server/123/alerts.xml
```